# Is there a function or variable to get a user's global system theme?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a website with a friend and I was wondering how do I get the current user's preferred theme that's set in their personalization settings (Usually dark or light)?
This is just so I can set the CSS of the site when the user loads the page, instead of them having to click it at the bottom of the page

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Answer (score 1):

There is a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) that will allow you to get it. It is still a draft level 5 (high enough to think it will make it to most browsers) but still be aware that it could change:

```
prefers-color-scheme

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {  .themed {    background: white;    color: black;  }}
```

It currently has three possible values: `light`, `dark` and `no-preference`. You should check it and  since it is still a draft you need to be aware that it might have changes in the future

Comment: Nice first answer!  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

We have 2 variants. With Back or With Front.

With Back you can set "light|dark-theme" to html element in back. And then you can control with front. And With that send XHR or fetch request to back for changing theme in base;

With Front you can use cookies. Save to Cookie how it make [youtube](https://youtube.com). And then change in cookies.